# .htaccess redirect only homepage, not when parameter in URL

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to forward the homepage only with a 301 redirect, that works with:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/$ https://www.site2.example/
```

But now I found a problem, that is when there is a parameter in the URL, then it will also forwarded to `site2.example`. That's not what I want.

The homepage must be forwarded to `https://www.site2.example/` but **only** when there is no parameter in the URL, like:

```
www.site1.example/?s=text
```

Only a visit on the homepage `www.site1.example/` should be forwarded to `www.site2.example/`.

I have tried a lot of things, but it doesn't work.
For example what I have tried is

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/?s=
RewriteRule ^$ https://www.site2.example/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: So you want to add a condition checking whether the query string is empty: `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$`

Comment: @arkascha That should be posted as an answer rather than as a comment. Comments are temporary and cannot be accepted as an answer. There is no mechanism for converting comments to answers, so I cannot do it for you. You will need to copy your comment into the answer box and then delete your comment.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller At the time of writing this seemed so obvious to me that I did not consider it worth an answer. But you are right, it does make sense. I added an answer below. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use a condition testing for an empty query string:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^/?$ https://www.site2.example/ [R=301,L]
```

Such rule is best implemented in the http server's host configuration. If you do not have access to that you can instead use a *distributed* configuration file (often called ".htaccess"), you need to enable the interpretation of such files then (see the documentation of the `AllowOverride` directive for that).